# Google Products / Repeating projects

Tags: google-product-search

I have an xml feed for google products. It's accepted by google and there are no any error messages except one. It says that the feed contains not unique product identifiers and doesn't accept 2/3 of the products. I can't understand why, all products are unique there. I tried to find the ids from the error message in the feed code and they occur there only once.

Can any advise something please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google products search are now strict on Standards. They now require amongst others UPC/GTIN/ISBN/EAN of products. OR Manufacturer and MPN.
So, in the nutshell, for each product, there should be UPC/GTIN OR (MPN and Manufacturer)
Failure to do so will result in your feed not published.
There is a free cool application on magento-connect that does it really well for Google and other price engines. [RetailTower Application for comparison engines](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/feed-manager-version-1-1-3.html)